# Typescript object with generic keys and regular keys?

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```js
type MyKeys = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'
```

I want to define a type that has keys of type `MyKeys`, but also extends it with more keys, like this:

```js
type FooType = {
  [key in MyKeys]: boolean
  quux: boolean   // <--- Error: '}' expected.ts(1005)
}
```

How can I use both generic keys and explicit key names?

Comment: I'm also not sure if "generic keys" is what you call this, nor if "explicit keys" makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [Intersection Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```js
type FooType = {[key in MyKeys]: boolean} & {
  quux: boolean
}
```

**or** as mentioned by @jcalz, you can also use `Record<>`:

```js
Record<MyKeys | 'quux', boolean>
```

that will equivalent to:

[image]

Comment: That's an [interesction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types), not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).

Comment: You can also do `Record<MyKeys | 'quux', boolean>`